# Google::Apis::AuthorizationError (Unauthorized) when calling get_userinfo_v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-oauth

I'm setting up a pretty rails API, and I need to receive an oauth2 token from google, and then use it to fetch the user's basic info (full name, email, etc).

The token is generated by a mobile app and sent to the API.

The following code, works to get the user's email but not the additional fields

```
def google(auth)
    require 'google/apis/oauth2_v2'

    oauth2 = Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new

    google_profile = oauth2.tokeninfo(id_token: auth)
end
```

I've tried to fetch the user's info calling userinfo in the following ways:

```
google_profile = oauth2.get_userinfo
google_profile = oauth2.get_userinfo_v2
```

But none of them work, I get `Google::Apis::AuthorizationError (Unauthorized)`

I can't seem to find a way to configure the gem to properly configure the authorization keys, I've tried

```
oauth2.key='AIz...ryg'
```

Also tried using an auth json like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id":"...",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret":"aZ...sl"
  }
}
```

But I always get the same exception. Calling `ex.body` returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
require 'google/apis/oauth2_v2'

tokens = { "id_token": ..., "access_token": ... }
oauth2 = Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new

tokeninfo = oauth2.tokeninfo(
  id_token: tokens["id_token"],
  access_token: tokens["access_token"],
) 
# the above works as we're providing tokens via params to oauth.tokeninfo method.

# for userinfo to work we need to set up authorization beforehand 
# as the method get_userinfo_v2 expects it:
oauth2.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(tokens)
google_profile = oauth2.get_userinfo_v2
print(google_profile.to_json)
# => {"email":"...","family_name":"Stankovic","given_name":"Dragan","id":"...","locale":"en","name":"Dragan Stankovic","picture":"...","verified_email":true}
```

**Note**: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ is really helpful to observe the actual requests/responses during oauth process but also it can be used to acquire `id_token` and `access_token` for testing purposes. I used `id_token` and `access_token` acquired this way to devise minimal example above.

**EDIT**: initially I suggested applying this: https://gist.github.com/skycocker/ba67e6756131fb43cf4963e024158be1
but that example is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Tried with that code, I'm now gettng 
Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:)
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}

Comment: last line or fetch_access_token! ?

Comment: the `fetch_access_token!` line

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Not sure if you already figured the solution out but for posterity I'll edit the answer to include the details that I confirmed work ok